# Why segmentation fault is caused by class variables order?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly

I've created following program :

```
class CLexer
{
public:

  CLexer( ) {
    iCursorPos = 0;
  }

  void putCharacter(char character)
  {
    if(character != ' ' && character != '\n') {
      m_strToken[iCursorPos] = character;
      iCursorPos++;
    }
    else {
      m_strToken[iCursorPos] = '\0';
      iCursorPos = 0;
    }
  }

private:

  char m_strToken[1024];
  int iCursorPos = 0;

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  CLexer lex;
  lex.putCharacter('m');
  return 0;
}
```

Assembler output produced by compiler :

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .text._ZN6CLexerC2Ev,"axG",@progbits,_ZN6CLexerC5Ev,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZN6CLexerC2Ev
    .type   _ZN6CLexerC2Ev, @function
_ZN6CLexerC2Ev:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $0, 1024(%rax)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $0, 1024(%rax)
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   _ZN6CLexerC2Ev, .-_ZN6CLexerC2Ev
    .weak   _ZN6CLexerC1Ev
    .set    _ZN6CLexerC1Ev,_ZN6CLexerC2Ev
    .section    .text._ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc,"axG",@progbits,_ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc,comdat
    .align 2
    .weak   _ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc
    .type   _ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc, @function
_ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movl    %esi, %eax
    movb    %al, -12(%rbp)
    cmpb    $32, -12(%rbp)
    je  .L3
    cmpb    $10, -12(%rbp)
    je  .L3
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    1024(%rax), %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    cltq
    movzbl  -12(%rbp), %ecx
    movb    %cl, (%rdx,%rax)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    1024(%rax), %eax
    leal    1(%rax), %edx
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %edx, 1024(%rax)
    jmp .L4
.L3:
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    1024(%rax), %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    cltq
    movb    $0, (%rdx,%rax)
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $0, 1024(%rax)
.L4:
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3:
    .size   _ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc, .-_ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB4:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $1056, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -1044(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -1056(%rbp)
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN6CLexerC1Ev
    leaq    -1040(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $109, %esi
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN6CLexer12putCharacterEc
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE4:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.1.1 20160501"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

And after execution, first call to putCharacter method with 'm' character as parameter is throwing segfault.
Attached gdb is giving following output :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004018e5 in CLexer::putCharacter (this=0x7fffffffe370, 
    character=109 'm') at src/main.cpp:60
60        m_strToken[iCursorPos] = character;
```

I've managed to fix this error by moving iCursorPos variable above m_strToken in class declaration but i think it isn't proper way to fix this issue.

I'm using `g++ (GCC) 6.1.1 20160501` on the lastest and updated version of `ArchLinux x86_64`.

Comment: And what is the value of iCursorPos, at this point?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @NathanOliver I've did it i think.

Comment: It runs fine in [ideone](https://ideone.com/65paxI).

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5be10f5b4e7de9df)

Comment: Is some structure packing in force?

Comment: I'am compining with flags : -std=gnu++14 -Wall -Iinclude/ -g and rest is unmodified.

Comment: No, you did not provide a [mcve]. Your bug cannot be reproduced. If there's a bug, it's a bug in the code you did not show. Just because there's a crash at a particular point does not mean that's where the bug is. Welcome to C++.

Comment: It might be reproducible example if you put something like `while(true) lex.putCharacter('m');` in your code's `main` function. This would continually add the character `m` in the buffer until it overflowed (overwriting the `iCursorPos`  member variable) and crashed per @StoryTeller answer. `src/main.cpp:60` in the output says the issue is on line 60, which means the code you are running is not what you presented to Stackoverflow (you don't have 60 lines in the code presented).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(character != ' ' && character != '\n') {
  m_strToken[iCursorPos] = character;
  iCursorPos++;
}
```

You don't check that `iCursorPos < 1024` here. So you write past the end of the buffer, into `iCursorPos` itself.

The next access `m_strToken[iCursorPos] = character;` probably writes way past the end of the buffer, and you get a segfault (luckily).

Your "fix" still isn't correct, since you corrupt other parts of your objects memory regardless.

Comment: Yes this indeed seems to be what is happening

Comment: This is another problem, However he wrote that it fails at first call.

Comment: He most probably wasn't accurate in describing the circumstances (and should have provided the calling code as well). This is what's wrong with the code as presented.

Comment: @PcAF He says the first time he calls it with `'m'` not the first time he ever calls the function.

Comment: I have updated code, any call (even first when value of counter should be 0 is providing segfault). Swapping variable positions fixses this issue.

Comment: @KacperFałat, [your code sample doesn't reproduce the problem](http://ideone.com/P7RApS)

Comment: @StoryTeller Now i think it's problem of my compiler.

Comment: @KacperFałat, no it's buggy code. If you don't do boundary checks, this is exactly the sort of hard to trace bugs you get. If you still insist not to check the value of `iCursorPos` before assignment, you'd just crash & burn at a later point.

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you so much, now i figured it out finally in proper way.